# creating shortcuts in local.xml

Tags: layout

I'm creating a local.xml for a new site. I'm working on the customer account pages and I'm finding that I have to repeat a lot of the same rules per page.

For the Sales Order History page I have

```
    <sales_order_history>
        <reference name="head">
           <action method="addCss">
               <stylesheet>css/custom/account.css</stylesheet>
           </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <remove name="customer.account.link.back" />
    </sales_order_history>
```

If there was a way to just save the xml inside the `sales_order_history` tags in a variable, eg. `{xmlRules} = sales_order_history` and then call it I think it would make the file much more readable.

```
  <sales_order_view>
     {xmlRules}
  </sales_order_view>
```

Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1) Define your layout XML under custom handle name:

```
<MY_XML_RULES>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom/account.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <remove name="customer.account.link.back" />
</MY_XML_RULES>
```

2) Apply it:

```
<sales_order_history>
    <update handle="MY_XML_RULES" />
</sales_order_history>
```